# Exclude Entity fields from updating process in forms Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm in a situation where the edit form of an Entity is a little bit different than the create form. I don't show some fields, because I don't want them to be editable.

But when I save this form, all not included fields are set to null and are saved, but I want to exclude those fields from the whole updating process.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options:

- Create the basic form type for editing and extend it to add additional fields for creating.
- Keep just one form type but add some fields conditionally — that is, only when the entity is new. You can get your entity in the form type as `$options['data']` and check if its ID is not `null` or whatever.
- Use [form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html).

Comment: Isn't the first approach a bit weird? Shouldn't the edit form extend the create form? So basically, could I turn fields off in the extended class and have the Form not `null` unset data?

Comment: Or to ask differently: Could you name up and downsides of the different options? Which one would you recommend and why.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to submit form instead of handleRequest and pass the second parameter     $clearMissing  to    false:

```
$editForm->submit($request->request->get('form_name'), false);
```